# Using same Model for MVVM and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvvm

I have a query regarding MVVM and MVC. I am developing an Desktop Client and Web application. I intend to use WPF (and MVVM) to develop desktop client and ASP.Net MVC for web app.

I have never used ASP.Net MVC before although I have never truly liked Web Forms (except some features like Master Page, output Cache etc.) and I mostly use AJAX (jQuery), and handlers to populate HTML and processing inputs (I think I was close to MVC after reading about the pattern but in a different way).

Now these applications will mostly have same inputs, reports, and database. I am planning to create Model that can be re-used in MVVM and MVC both. But after reading various articles on these pattern, and analysis of ASP.Net MVC Code, I doubt that it could be done. In MVVM, View never knows Model while in MVC, Controller shares Model with View. Also, in ASP.Net MVC, a View (ASPX file) is derived from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage and the labels/captions are populated from Model itself.

Is there a way I can use same Model for both applications?

Thank you.

Ritesh

Comment: "In MVVM, View never knows Model" nope.  Not correct.  The view binds against models.

Comment: @Will: Nah. It binds to the VM as Darin describes.

Comment: @Will - In MVVM, we do not directly bind controls with model. There are bridging properties in ViewModel for binding.

Comment: @Ritesh: That incorrect belief has probably cost you some coding time, unfortunately.

Comment: @jgauffin: :| There is no reason why you cannot bind to models, if your models are designed to support this.  And if not, you can use custom type descriptors to bridge the gap.  Hell, you can even autogenerate the code for them via a T4 template.  Why wrap every model to hide it from the view?  Its a waste of time.

Comment: @Will - I am open to ideas. Could you please tell me how can I use/create type descriptors to bridge the gap?

Comment: @Ritesh: WPF bindings inspect your types to see if they implement ICustomTypeDescriptor or if there are any custom type descriptors defined for your types, and will prefer binding to this rather than the actual underlying type.  You can use custom type descriptors to control what reflection reveals about your type's properties, events, methods, metadata, etc.  So you can, for example, expose an `IList<T>` property as an ICollection<T> that implements INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: The process of creating a custom type descriptor (and property descriptors) seems difficult at first, but its actually quite easy.  You can always offload tasks you don't care about (e.g., metadata) to the TypeDescriptor static class, and control only that which you need to.  To see an example of the power you get leveraging this, check out how [the WF4 team turns POCOs into fully featured view models](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2011/04/11/wf4-modelitem-modelitemimpl-and-icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) with undo/redo support, INCC, INPC, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In MVVM, View never knows Model while in MVC, Controller shares Model with View.

Not quite right. In MVVM the view is bound to a view model. Exactly the same as in ASP.NET MVC. In ASP.NET MVC a Controller doesn't share a Model with the View. It shares a View Model. It talks to the Model and then builds a View Model that is passed to the View.

Contrary to MVC in MVVM the View could talk to the Model but this happens indirectly throughout the View Model, so neither the View nor the Model know about each other's existence.

So you could perfectly fine have the same Models in both your Desktop client application and in your web application. The only difference will be the view models.

Comment: Thank you. Here is a sample property from LogOnModel class created by ASP.Net MVC Template in VS2010.
`[Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [DisplayName("Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }`

The attributes seem to be applicable to ASP.Net MVC only. Should I keep these attributes for MVVM as well?

Comment: `LogOnModel` is not the Model. It's the View Model, because as I already stated in my answer in a properly written MVC application you never pass your Models to the View. You pass only View Models. The Model should not contain any view specific attributes such as `DisplayName`. So make a clean reusable Model and then define View Models for both your MVC and desktop applications.